# Download Google Map from a website and show it from android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm Planning to build an android app as a support for a website. This site shows a map with all the nodes and links they have installed around a territory, in this case, Spain. My goal is to access from my app to this map download it updated and show it from the phone. The map in the website is google map and the android phone may support it without problems. Is there any easy wait to do so?

The site from which I want to download the map is this: http://www.guifi.net/ca/maps

Thank you in advance!